# Hatching Plotly go.Scattergeo

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have polygon on a map. There is as way to have a hatch fill for my polygon ? This is a code snippet:

```
    polygon_lat = [48.8566, 48.8594, 48.8607, 48.8584]
    polygon_lon = [2.3522, 2.3618, 2.3443, 2.3465]
    
    # Filled polygon, full contour
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        lon=polygon_lon + [polygon_lon[0]],  
        lat=polygon_lat + [polygon_lat[0]],
        mode='lines+markers',  
        fill='toself',  
        fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)',  
        line=dict(width=2, color='rgba(0,100,80,0.5)'),  
    ))
    # Filled polygon, dash contour
    # fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    #     lon=polygon_lon + [polygon_lon[0]], 
    #     lat=polygon_lat + [polygon_lat[0]],
    #     fill = 'toself',  
    #     fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)', 
    #     mode='lines',  
    #     line=dict(width=2, color='rgba(0,100,80,0.5)', dash='dash'),  
    # ))
    fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")
    return fig
```